# How can i display sold products for 10 days in magento 1.9.3

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to display sold products for 10 days after customer ordered that product in magento 1.9.3

Comment: Did you write short description where you want to show the products?

Comment: I want to display in category product page

Comment: Order contain product id you can fetch from order item table

Answer (score 0):

It's not very difficult with the report classes :

```
$from = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-10 days'));
$to = date('Y-m-d');

$productIds = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_ordered_collection')
    ->setDateRange($from, $to)
    ->getColumnValues('entity_id');
```

You now have an array of all the IDs of products ordered the 10 last days, you are free to load a product collection filtered with this array, like that :

```
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addIdFilter($orders);
```

Comment: Hi oddBrew, thanks for your reply, sorry i am mentioned exact what i need, i want to display category products (In stock products) and sold products (last 10 days sold products).

Answer (score 0):

To reply to your comment : the code in my answer above this one will give you a collection of the last 10 days sold products that you can exploit. If you want to filter products that are out of stock, use this piece of code on the collection above :

```
Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')
    ->addInStockFilterToCollection($products);
```

You can add a category filter too if you need :

```
$products->addCategoryFilter($categoryModel);
```